# Info Window on shapes(circle, polygon) in Android Maps App

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon, infowindow, shapes

I have an android app which one of its screens uses google maps, and I load some regions on it. I want to be able to click on a region/shape(circle or polygon) and an info window to appear. I am searching but I cant find enough  information on how to show info windows on shapes, only on markers. Is that not  a common practice? What should I do? Could anyone help, even theoretically? Any help or direction would be appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a `customCircleOnClickListener` (or don't and use the title and
   snippet properties, as I am doing in step 3).
2. Then add:

   ```
   mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new
   CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MainActivity.this));
   mMap.setOnCircleClickListener(customCircleOnClickListener());
   ```
3. Finally:

   ```
   public GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener customCircleOnClickListener() {
       return new GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCircleClick(Circle circle) {
               Log.d("MainActivity", "Clicked a ball!");

               POIAnnotationCircle annotCircle = annotationsByCircle.get(circle);
               markerForInfoWindow = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                       .alpha(0.0f)
                       .infoWindowAnchor(.6f,1.0f)
                       .position(annotCircle.getCoordinate())
                       .title(annotCircle.getTitle())
                       .snippet(annotCircle.getSnippet()));

               markerForInfoWindow.showInfoWindow();
           }
       };
   }
   ```